# How to flag answers written in a different language?

Tags: support

Question is based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45550451/2263631) answer, what flag option do you use? Is the NAA (not an answer) flag suitable?

**Update**

The answer has been updated to include the English version, however the question still stands. What to do in those scenarios?